# Probability plots for logistic regression estimated with survey/svyglm including polynoms

Tags: r, survey, margins, sjplot

I'm trying to visualize a second-order polynomial in a logistic regression model estimated with the `svyglm` command in R's `survey` package to account for survey weights. In particular, I'm searching for conditional effect and probability plots. However, all attempts seem to fail. So far I tried functions from the packages `sjPlot`, `margins`, `jtools` and `interplot` as well as using `I(var^2)` and `polynom(var, 2, raw=TRUE)`. Package documentations don't provide much help on the `survey::svyglm`-issue. Any hints at useful packages as well as correct syntax specifications for the packages mentioned above are highly appreciated!

Comment: You could try the `ggpredict()` function of the [ggeffects package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggeffects)

Comment: See `?ggpoly` for examples with polynomial terms and `ggpredict()`.

Comment: This helps! Many thanks!